# How can I get Json data in PHP which pass through AJAX function

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have an AJAX function like below, which will send a Json data to PHP file, How can I get these data in PHP file ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data11.php',
    data: {
        json: ko.toJSON(viewModel)
    },
    success: function () {}
});
```

My Json data is something like below

```
{"participants":[{"NoPrticiField":1,"empname":"gfh","designation":"fh","email":"fgh"},{"NoPrticiField":2,"empname":"fgh","designation":"fgh","email":"fgh"}]}:
```

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['json']);`

Answer (score 1):

Variables will be stored in either the $_POST or $_GET global variable.

You can retrieve it with the following:

```
$_POST['json'];
```

You can then also decode it with:

```
json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

Essentially PHP automatically stores all post and get variables into a sort of dictionary for you.

Take a look at:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php
https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php